# How to make an image appear until the half of every device screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my .xml file i have this format:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_orientation="vertical"...>

<ImageView>...
</ImageView>

<ScrollView ...>

    <TableLayout..>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

for the imageView,i would like to have height until the half of the screen (in any screen size),and then start my tableLayout in the other half of the screen!Is that  possible?thanks

Comment: i use this in several classes,with different height of images..so i just want to cut my screen in the middle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Layout_weight .

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    </ImageView>

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000">

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>][1]
```

It gives the look you are looking for .

Comment: and the android:layout_height and width of imageView and ScrollView??

Comment: do you not need to add a weight sum of 2 to the parent LinearLayout as well?

Comment: sorry but i tried it and i only get a picture in my hole screen...is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  android:layout_weight property to specify how much space each child view should take up. Take a look @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html, specifically the linearlayout part for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="0dp">
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Open"
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="New"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Save"
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Exit"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```